# replaceReducer cause reducer called many times in redux

Tags: redux

I use **store.replaceReducer** to load async module reducers.

```
            const reducers = store.reducers; // reducer dictionary to cache

        if (reducers.indexOf(reducer) === -1 && reducer !== defaultReducer) {

            reducers.push(reducer);
            const reducerObj = {};

            reducers.forEach((reducerItem) => {
                Object.assign(reducerObj, reducerItem);
            });

            store.replaceReducer(combineReducers(reducerObj));
```

when I **dispath** an action in **first module**, **reducer** called as expected.

But when **replaceReducer** is used to append new reducers to **store**, previous reducer will be called again,and will call after **replaceReducer** every time .

how can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this happens only if you are using the dev tools. See https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/issues/291